# Use global variable to store Data session

Tags: php, session, wordpress

I am using a plugin which is Groups. This allows to handle groups, hierarchy and capabilities. Using this, I can restrict the access to post to some groups of users.

The API provided by this plugin has a Class which has a method giving me back all the accessible posts for the current user. I have to provide as parameters all the posts (via get_posts method) and the $wpdb.

As you can see, each time I call this method, queries are done, I really want to avoid it.

So, my question is what is the best way to handle it ?

A way should be to have a global variable (as SESSION, but I saw wordpress wasn't using it), in which I could store session variables as accessible posts. I could initiate this variable with the wp_login hook.

I really want to do something safe.

Comment: There's no reason that you can't store that information in the session and pass those as the parameters as opposed to performing a query with get posts and passing the result in. However, it should be noted that you will need to update that session each time new posts are available.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Otherwise, I could use a singleton class in which I put my session data and method ? 
I though Wordpress had some specific hooks or class to handle this.